# Mutt macros: How to set and then use a variable in one macro?

Tags: macros, mutt

I'm trying to write a small mutt macro that will set a variable, and then re-use that variable in the same macro.

What I'm really trying to do is compose a message and sub in the To: address (which later I will populate dynamically).

This is in my .muttrc

```
set my_to = "bobby@test.com"
macro index E "<enter-command> set my_to = barry@test.com<enter>mn\$my_to"
```

My problem is the variable **my_to** never changes from **bobby@...** to **barry@...**

I believe it has to do with the **$** being interpreted during the config parsing, and the manual recommends using an escape . But if I do that, only the literal **"$my_to"** shows up.

What am I doing wrong?

*update:*
I still haven't been able to set/get variables as above, but I'd missed an obvious Mutt solution to my problem *ESC*-e will create a new email based on the existing. Similar to the edit-as-new in Thunderbird.